# How to deploy JFrame in web page?

Tags: java, web, applet

So I have done my research about deploying an applet or jframe in a web page. I have created my jar file and the html file to launch it. I get an error when trying to load the page that says Java Runtime Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException...I have searched this error and from what I understand it means that the class that I am calling is not an applet.

Here is some code snippets on what I am doing.

HTML file-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Monitor</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="data.simulation.front.Main.class" archive="Monitor2.jar" height="844" width="1244"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Main class that has my main() function.

```
public class Main implements DBConstants {

// insets set the space between all the components
private static final Insets insets = new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12);
private static JPanel innerFrame; // panel that all sub panels are snapped
                                    // to
private static ColorFrame cFrame; // panel that displays line colors
private static VoltageFrame vFrame; // panel that displays the voltage graph
private static FrequencyFrame fFrame; // panel that displays the frequency
                                        // graph
private static DisturbanceFrame dFrame; // panel that displays the
                                        // disturbance frame
private static Toolbar toolbar; // contains all the JButtons
final static JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame(); // application frame
                                                        // that contains
                                                        // innerFrame and
                                                        // toolbar

// global variables to open connection of db and keep open for duration of
// applet
// connection gets closed only when the frame is closed by the exit button
// will not close conn when end program is clicked from within eclipse
public static Connection dbConnection = null; //
public static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null; //

/**
 * Main is the starting point of the application and will open a connection
 * to the database first and then set up the application frame which will
 * hold all of the inner components
 * 
 * @param args
 *            param args not used
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // start connection of database
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("DB CONNECTION OPENED");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int toolsHeight = 25;
    int appWidth = 1244;
    int appHeight = toolsHeight + 819;

    applicationFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(appWidth, appHeight));
    applicationFrame.setTitle("Phasor Measurement Unit Display");
    applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    applicationFrame.setResizable(true);
    applicationFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    toolbar = new Toolbar();
    Main.setInnerFrame(new JPanel());
    Main.getInnerFrame().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    Main.getInnerFrame().setBackground(new Color(190, 190, 190));

    applicationFrame.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    cFrame = new ColorFrame(GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST);
    vFrame = new VoltageFrame(GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);
    fFrame = new FrequencyFrame(GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST);
    dFrame = new DisturbanceFrame(GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST);

    applicationFrame.add(innerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    applicationFrame.pack();
    applicationFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
    innerFrame.revalidate();
    applicationFrame.validate();
    applicationFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        /*
         * Window listener to listen to when the window is closed via the x
         * button. When the window is closed the connection the database is
         * also closed
         */
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                try {
                    dbConnection.close();
                    System.out.println("DB CONNECTION CLOSED");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The class Main does not extend Applet but I have tried that with no luck. I have tried moving the jar and html file into my classes folder. I have tried to extend applet and change main() to start(). I have tried many other things to get this to work.

Any help or recommendations is much appreciated.
This is my first question on SO so excuse me if it is not structured properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you consulted the Java Applets [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) from Oracle?

Comment: To run as Applet you *must* extend Applet. Be wary that (unsigned) applets are restricted in many ways (see rriowers link, What Applets cannot do). Debug your application methodically from the bottom to the top, not in reverse - meaning start with a simple helloworld applet, then *add* feature by feature util it breaks. I presume you are aware that applets are a dying technology, e.g. the Java plugin is not available by default in current browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have consulted the Java Applets tutorials and I am aware that the applets are dying. I was assigned to the project for an internship and was requested to put the applet in a web page. My mentor knows nothing about applets. Can I just extend applet and add another method to essentially call my main to start the applet from the web page? Also what would be an alternative to get this displayed in a browser other than using an applet?

Comment: *"My mentor knows nothing about applets."* They are foolish for asking an intern to do something they don't know how to.  Any Java code launched off the net now has to be digitally signed by a valid code signing certificate.  It would be easier to launch the `JFrame` direct from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will still need to be digitally signed, but you can avoid all of the (many) problems with deploying an embedded applet.